# .txt file content need to be copied to existing excel sheet without deleting other sheet information

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I already have the excel-sheet named test.xls which has 3 worksheets (Files1, Files2 and Results). Now I need to copy the text file content and write it to the 'Results' worksheet.

Below is the C# code that I worked on.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\test.txt");
            string line = "";
            int counter = 0;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    lstColumnNames.AddRange(line.Split(' '));
                }
                else
                {
                    List<string> tempRowData = new List<string>();
                    tempRowData.AddRange(line.Split(' '));
                    lstRowData.Add(tempRowData);
                }
                counter++;
            }
            System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\test.xlsx");


            if (lstColumnNames.Count != 0)
            {
                string temp = "";
                foreach (string str in lstColumnNames)
                {
                    if (temp != "")
                    {
                        temp += ";";
                    }
                    temp += str;
                }
                tw.WriteLine(temp);


                foreach (List<string> lstRow in lstRowData)
                {
                    temp = "";

                    foreach (string str in lstRow)
                    {
                        if (temp != "")
                        {
                            temp += ";";
                        }
                        temp += str;
                    }
                    tw.WriteLine(temp);
                }
                tw.Close();
```

The above code deleted all the worksheets and write the text file content into new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

It overwrites the current content because you're missing an overload for the `StreamWriter`. If you pass `true` then you will put `StreamWriter` into `Append` mode.

```
... new StreamWriter(@"C:\MyFile.xlsx", true);
```

I wouldn't recommend trying to manipulate Excel this way. There's a proper tool for the job called `Excel Interop` which will let you do what you want. There are lots of tutorials available on read/writing data this way, here are a few I've found:

[MSDN - Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[DotNetPerls Excel Interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)
[CSharp.NET - How to open an Excel file in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm)
[CodeProject - Faster Excel Reading using Interop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9992/Faster-MS-Excel-Reading-using-Office-Interop-Assem)

Some good reading about how to tidy up after yourself when using Excel Interop:
[How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/158752#158752)